# How to install VLC 2.2 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ppa, vlc

I want to install VLC 2.2 Weatherwax in the Ubuntu (well, Xubuntu) 14.04 LTS release.
There is a PPA from Videolan on Launchpad that offers more recent VLC releases for Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.

Except there is a problem. The official PPA from Videolan for Ubuntu 14.04 does not contain all the libraries needed to run VLC on Ubuntu 14.04. It seems the VLC developers made their package require some 3rd-party repositories that they didn't think to include in their PPA.

So what I'm wondering is where can I find all the libraries I need to run an non-outdated version of VLC on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### [ppa:mc3man/trusty-media](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media)

From the PPA description:

> Upgraded, advanced or not normally available multimedia packages for Trusty

It contains the latest version of VLC, ffmpeg, and some other popular video players and important media libraries. The PPA is pecifically for users looking for media updates without ditching the LTS release.

Comment: This works on Mint 17.1, but be warned: you're not supposed to use Ubuntu PPAs with Mint. This PPA for the most part does not break anything, but if you want to install DeSmuME (or other such programs with version-specific X-related library dependencies,) you'll enter APT hell: Dependency Edition.

Comment: I've no issue here installing desmume here on 14.04. Are you using a Mint build?.

Comment: @doug Yes - this Ubuntu PPA, when used on Mint, breaks DeSmuME.

Comment: If you know a link to mint's source for their DeSmuME build would like to take a look. For comparison sent a 0.9.10 build to a test ppa that deps on the media ppa. No issues at all & when checking build log only used 1 package from the ppa, vorbis. So can't see why it would give you issue installing..

Comment: More likely the issue with desmume is mesa, atm 14.04.2 lts mesa will not allow libosmesa6 so no desmume in 14.04.2 or later. https://bugs.launchpad.net/mesa/+bug/1422139

Comment: @oche: Instructions on how to install the PPA can be found with a single click on the PPA's page itself (right alongside all the appropriate warnings and a quick description of what a PPA is.) It's better that users see that information before installing a PPA than simply getting used to copy-pasting commands which add untrusted 3rd-party repositories to their systems..